# Visual Studio 2013 crashing when opening solution on Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-10

Yesterday I upgraded my Windows 10 machine from the Insider Preview to the original release. From that moment on when I try to open solution(even when trying to create new one) in Visual Studio 2013 the program crashes and stops. In the event viewer I found that the crash is due to a heap corruption in the ntdll.dll but that didn't help me. The program runs smoothly in safe mode but crashes every time with every solution when not in this mode. 
When this happened I thought that it should be common problem for Windows 10 and VS2013 but I can't find anything relevant in the net for almost a day. Does anybody else experience such issue or similar? Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Note: I worked with VS2013 and Windows 10 Insider preview for almost a month and experienced no issues. That's why I think the problem is connected with the official release of Windows 10.

Comment: I too upgraded to Windows 10 in place. That caused my Visual Studio 2013 to crash when opening solutions about 20% of the time. It's very annoying! I had installed VS Update 5 prior to upgrading to Windows 10.

Comment: I have a fresh Win10, and I'm crashing everytime I open a solution.  I just uninstalled VS13, and reinstalled, still crashing.  I'll post solution when I find.

Comment: Same problem, same DLL reported. Installed windows 10, was fine for a week, but another batch of updates came through and this problem started occurring.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try un-installing VS2013 and then re-installing it on your machine, this works for almost all of the bugs that I encounter when upgrading my OS. Also, make sure you are installing VS2013 Update 5, which was released on the 20th July this year, and not the old VS2013 Update 4 (Or possibly earlier if you are using an old installer) as this may fix compatibility issues, which is likely as Microsoft would have made the most recent version of the software compatible with its latest OS. Even better, try installing Visual Studio 2015 as this will almost certainly be Windows 10 compatible as it is the newest release of the Visual Studio software.

Edit: Don't forget to back up any projects you want to keep before making any changes! This is important as you could easily lose a lot of work when un-installing VS2013.

Comment: I've already installed update 5 but it doesn't help. I don't have time right now to migrate to VS2015.I hoped to avoid the reinstalling but it may be the only way...

Comment: It would be nice to avoid reinstalling however after taking a look online I haven't found any other option, I will keep looking around online and I will let you know if I find anything that might help